# conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

***ACADEMIE:***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[R_ACADEMIE](
    [ID_ACADEMIE] [dbo].[IDENTIFIANT] NOT NULL,
    [LC_ACADEMIE_CODE] [dbo].[LIBELLE_COURT] NOT NULL,
    [LM_ACADEMIE_LIBELLE] [dbo].[LIBELLE_MOYEN] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_R_ACADEMIE] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_ACADEMIE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I add my column in my `E_VOYAGEUR` table

```
ALTER TABLE E_VOYAGEUR ADD ID_ACADEMIE IDENTIFIANT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

I want to create a FK on my `E_VOYAGEUR` table i do this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[E_VOYAGEUR]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_E_VOYAGE_A_VOYAGEU_E_ACADEMIE] FOREIGN KEY([ID_ACADEMIE])
REFERENCES [dbo].[R_ACADEMIE] ([ID_ACADEMIE])
GO
```

***i have this error:***

> The ALTER TABLE statement is in conflict with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint " FK_E_VOYAGE_A_VOYAGEU_E_ACADEMIE " . The conflict
>   occurred in database " DEV ", " dbo.R_ACADEMIE " table, column '
>   ID_ACADEMIE ' .

Comment: It sounds like you have ID_ACADEMIE values in E_VOYAGEUR that do not exist in R_ACADEMIE. A foreign key cannot be added against existing data when some values do not exist in the referenced table. You will need to insert the missing values.

Comment: @SMM i update my post. In `R_ACADEMIE` i have `ID_ACADEMIE`

Comment: Did you insert the values from E_VOYAGEUR.ID_ACADEMIE as rows in R_ACADEMIE? e.g. You added the new column to E_VOYAGEUR with `not null default 0`...do you have a record in R_ACADEMIE with ID_ACADEMIE = 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your table E_VOYAGEUR already having some values And you are altering that table to add the new column ID_ACADEMIE with default value as 0.
This makes all the rows in the table E_VOYAGEUR with 0 value for the columnn ID_ACADEMIE . And when you are adding with the foreigh key constraint to that table ,reference table, [R_ACADEMIE] may not have an entry with value '0' in the column ID_ACADEMIE and that seems to be the cause of this issue.

Before adding the foreign key to the table E_VOYAGEUR,make sure the value in the column ID_ACADEMIE having references in the table [R_ACADEMIE] .