# Unable to make desired JOINS between multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I've got 3 tables

Plan:

```
 plan_id   emp_id   duration
  123       1010    30
  456       1011    40
  789       1012    60
```

PlanEmp:

```
plan_id emp_id
 123    2131
 456    3131
 789    4131
```

Emp:

```
emp_id  Name
1010    Andy
1011    Cole
1012    John
2131    Sam
3131    Kim
4131    Ray
```

**Desired Summary Output:**

```
plan_id   Name   duration
 123      Andy   30
 123      Sam    30
 456      Cole   40
 456      Kim    40
 789      John   60
 789      Ray    60
```

Query that I'm trying to modify to get the above result:

```
SELECT P.plan_id 
      ,E.Name
      ,P.duration
FROM Plan P
LEFT JOIN Emp E
    ON P.emp_id = E.emp_id
LEFT JOIN PlanEmp PE
    ON P.plan_id = PE.plan_id
```

I'm unable to figure how to pull the Employee details using the PlanEmp table AND the Plan table to get the summary output.

Comment: union plan and planemp and then join

Comment: SELECT P.plan_id 
      ,E.Name
      ,P.duration
FROM Plan P
LEFT JOIN Emp E
    ON P.emp_id = E.emp_id should do it

Comment: What happens if there's more than one duration per plan/employee mapping - which one do you use as the basis in the other table?  If the data is populated differently, why should you even be reusing the data from the other table, and are you sure that those columns actually correlate?

Comment: The mapping is done such that multiple employees with different roles can be listed on the same plan. So they will have all other plan details (like duration) common besides the employee name itself. Emp id's get segregated in different tables (Emp id will not be the same for a particular plan id between the two tables). But if you want their corresponding details, you gotta access the Employee table.

Comment: Would've made more sense to have another 'role_id' in the `PlanEmp` table and not have emp_id's in the `Plan` table. I would if I had control over the database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT sub.plan_id, sub.emp_id, Emp.name, Plan.duration
FROM
(SELECT plan_id, emp_id
FROM Plan
UNION
SELECT plan_id, emp_id
FROM PlanEmp) sub
LEFT JOIN Emp
ON sub.emp_id = Emp.emp_id
LEFT JOIN Plan
ON sub.plan_id = Plan.plan_id
ORDER BY plan_id
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21ca79/4

Answer (score 2):

Use the below script.

```
  ;With cte_1
  As( select plan_id,emp_id
         From plan
        UNION 
         Select plan_id,emp_id
          From plan_emp)

     Select c.plan_id,e.Name,p.Duration
      From cte_1 c
         Join plan p on c.plan_id=p.plan_id
          Join emp e on c. Emp_id=e.emp_id
```

Comment: May I suggest adding more than code to your answers? Giving someone an answer to a question without explaining the logic will only lead to follow on questions and/or follow on errors in their code if they don't know what your code is doing or why you chose the methods you do. "Code Only Answers" are generally recognized as low quality answers. This one, for example, is far better http://stackoverflow.com/a/39020960/6167855 and more answers like it will help you with your "points goal" reference here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39247701/6167855 and will truly help other users. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a logical explanation for this and since my reputation is not at the level to comment yet, but why is `emp_id` on both the `Plan and PlanEmp tables`? If you can normalize this, that would be a good idea to move `emp_id` off of the `Plan table` to the `PlanEmp table`.

Comment: It's denormalized for performance and also because logically, the folks listed in the `Plan` have different roles as those in `PlanEmp` and their data is populated differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is not following the needed Normalization practices. You should merge the table Plan and EmpPlan.

or

Your design should be (To normalize more):

```
Table: Plan
Plan_ID
Duration

Table: PlanEmp
Plan_ID
Emp_ID
```

Your existing structure can be queried with multiple ways but they may not efficient. Another way:

```
Select ISNULL(P.plan_id, PE.plan_id) Plan_ID, E.Name,
(Select Duration from @Plan pp Where pp.plan_id = ISNULL(P.plan_id, PE.plan_id)) as Duration
from Emp E
left Join @lan P on E.emp_id = P.emp_id
left Join PlanEmp PE on E.emp_id = PE.emp_id
Where P.emp_id IS NOT NULL or PE.emp_id is not null
```